# Copying zeroes into a char array clears other char array as well

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, buffer

```
char x[30];
char* y[5];
int count = 0;
ifstream i("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
```

x reads 30 bytes of file from the ifstream buffer. y stores a random string.

```
while (i.read(x, sizeof(x)) {
    y[count] = x;
    printf("%s\n", y[0]); //This prints "test\n"
    bzero(x, sizeof(x)); //Clear the contents of array x
    printf("%s\n", y[0]); //This prints "\n"
    count++
}
```

For this example, assume that the file contains less than or equal to 150 bytes of data.

Why does this keep on happening? I observe the same behavior even if I use memset. How do I fix it?

Comment: How `x` and `y` (or `y[0]`) is related?

Comment: The array y is supposed to store the bytes read from the file using x. At the end of the iterations, I want y to contain the stored values.

Comment: Could you please provide a verifiable (compilable) example?

Comment: My bet is that you're assigning y[0] to x in your read loop, instead of allocating memory and copying

Comment: You are allocating memory to the 5 elements of `char *y[5]` aren't you?...  y[0] =malloc(SOME_VAL);, ... y[4] = malloc(SOME_VAL);

Comment: Reminder:  the `y` array is an array of pointers not characters.

Comment: I was indeed assigning y[0] = x, I see the problem now. Thanks!

Comment: @ExtremistEnigma - an upclick or _answered_ check to the answer-er  would be appropriate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `y[0]` is a pointer, it can point to (or into) `x`. The behavior you are observing suggests that it does. If `y[0]` points to (or into) `x`, then changing `x`'s contents will change the contents that `y[0]` points to.